# How to turn off *multi display* in c#?

Tags: c#

There are many articles about "how to turn off monitors in c#", but they all turn off all the monitors. Is there any possible way to turn off a particular monitor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little bit of research lead me here:

http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1011720#post1011720

Do you know how to call a function like that in c#?

-- Edit

Looks like this guy has done it all for you:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Display_Settings.aspx

Answer (score 1):

For calling **Win32** Functions not exposed in the .NET Framework
PInvoke.net
is a good ressource.

The function mentioned in the link of silky can be found **[here](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/ChangeDisplaySettingsEx.html)**.
Also have a look at the used data types.
Just copy the code mentioned in "C# Signature" to your project.

Answer (score -1):

Given that the monitor belongs to the user, not you, why do you want to turn it off.

This is just the sort of think I think a OS should protect me from when a application tries it, so expect problems…

Comment: I have quad monitor setup. 19 + 19 + 19 as working machine, and 30'' for movie, drama, and etc. I usually do not use 30'', so I would like to get control of it. Of course, I can just turn it on/off with power button. However, as a programmer, I just want to know:)