# Change monitor/screen position

Tags: winapi, multiple-monitors

Is there a way I can **programatically** move my screens in relation to each other? I want to put the 2nd display to the left instead of right. I know this can be done by right-clicking the desktop, choosing properties and then drag-drop there, but I want to do this using the Windows API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this thread: [How to turn off *multi display* in c#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311248/1321631), it shows an API for monitor adjustment, and a wrapper for .NET (if that's what you're using).

Comment: Thanks, this looks like the thing i'm looking for:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Display_Settings.aspx